# HTML issues on a testimonial section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I wanted to create a testimonial section on my website to look something like this

[Ideal concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHGbS.png)

I was hoping to use only html and css, but sadly I was having some trouble with the logic for that.
While looking around, I stumbled on foundation. Felt like it would really help, so I rewrote my code with foundation and decided to use the tabs functionality.

I used

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>Testimonials | Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/foundation.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/additional.css">
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).foundation();
</script>
</head>

<div class="row">
<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
    <div class="column large-8 large-offset-2 end testimonialBox">
        <blockquote class="tabs-panel is-active large-8 column medium-offset-2 text-center plusclass end" id="panel1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente cum autem corporis vero voluptatum molestias reiciendis, nostrum necessitatibus nesciunt, delectus repellat tempora sint, in architecto. Reprehenderit eveniet molestiae nesciunt dolor ipsam deleniti voluptatibus maxime sequi a ullam nihil, ex dicta soluta.<cite>Famous Guy 1</cite></blockquote>
        <blockquote class="tabs-panel large-8 column medium-offset-2 text-center plusclass end" id="panel2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim tempora tempore quaerat perferendis, ab a earum, neque quis odio amet error ipsum sint nihil unde similique illum. Facere iure magnam aliquam doloremque, hic velit omnis.<cite>Famous Guy 2</cite></blockquote>         
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
    <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

But using that, all I got was
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMIwA.png)
 the first blockquote and the 2 tabs, and If I click on Tab2, it would  not show the second blockquote. It would do absolutely nothing.
Cicking on Tab1 would jerk the page to the top of the Blockquote 1.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: can you please make a working example? jsfiddle (p.e.)

Comment: Ah I will. 

The script tag issue came from when I was editting on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with your javascript syntax.

It should look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

and not like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the weird behaviour because the initialization call is happening before your content is rendered.

You need to move `$(document).foundation()` after your content (suitably at the bottom of the `body`) so that the tabs are properly initialized.

Also, I don't know if it was a copy error, but you're missing a closing `div` tag. Your updated html would then be:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Testimonials | Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/foundation.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/additional.css">
  <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/foundation.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="row">
  <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
    <div class="column large-8 large-offset-2 end testimonialBox">
      <blockquote class="tabs-panel is-active large-8 column medium-offset-2 text-center plusclass end" id="panel1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente cum autem corporis vero voluptatum molestias reiciendis, nostrum necessitatibus nesciunt, delectus repellat tempora sint, in architecto. Reprehenderit eveniet molestiae nesciunt
        dolor ipsam deleniti voluptatibus maxime sequi a ullam nihil, ex dicta soluta.<cite>Famous Guy 1</cite></blockquote>
      <blockquote class="tabs-panel large-8 column medium-offset-2 text-center plusclass end" id="panel2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim tempora tempore quaerat perferendis, ab a earum, neque quis odio amet error ipsum sint nihil unde similique illum. Facere iure magnam aliquam doloremque, hic velit omnis.<cite>Famous Guy 2</cite></blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
    <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```